# Is there a need for DMB if we are using DSB

Tags: arm

Is DSB the superset of DMB ?

If performnace is not a consideration can DMB be replaced by a DSB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DSB` is superset of `DMB` so it can be replaced by a `DSB` if performance is not a concern.

From [Cortex-A Series Programmer's Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013d/index.html):

> **Data Synchronization Barrier (DSB)**
>
> This instruction forces the core to
>   wait for all pending explicit data accesses to complete before any
>   additional instructions stages can be executed. There is no effect on
>   pre-fetching of instructions.
>
> **Data Memory Barrier (DMB)**
>
> This
>   instruction ensures that all memory accesses in program order before
>   the barrier are observed in the system before any explicit memory
>   accesses that appear in program order after the barrier. It does not
>   affect the ordering of any other instructions executing on the core,
>   or of instruction fetches.